# How do I add a Bootswatch theme to a Vue project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootswatch

I have Bootstrap working properly in my Vue project.  I would like to use a theme from Bootswatch.  In my Vue project, I replaced the node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css file with one that I downloaded from the Bootswatch site.  But the new theme didn't change anything.  Note: In my main.js I have the following:

import 'bootstrap'

How do I properly get the new theme to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the css file in main.js as follows

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Make sure you have configured your webpack to use [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

**or**

In your root component(mostly App.vue) add two style tags , one for global styles and other for scoped styles if you have any with the scoped attribute.See [src imports.](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/start/spec.html)

```
<style src='path/to/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css'>
    /* global styles */
</style> 

<style scoped>
    /* local styles */
</style>
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to alter the path slightly.  I added this  to my main.js file:  import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Answer (score 3):

- Start by installing some dependencies:

  `yarn add bootstrap bootswatch jquery popper.js`

  ---
- Then add this lines to your entry point file `main.js`:


  `import "bootstrap";
  import "../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/lux/bootstrap.min.css";
  import "jquery";
  import "popper.js";`

  > `lux` is a theme name, so you can replace it with a theme of your
  >   choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your browser cache and restarting whatever vue is running on

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use npm...

```
npm install bootstrap bootswatch jquery popper.js

Then add this lines to your entry point file main.js:

import "bootstrap";
import "../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/theme/bootstrap.min.css";
import "jquery";
import "popper.js"

replace theme with your theme (journal,lux...)
```